# How do I generate a Postgres dump with the column names in my INSERT statement?

Tags: postgresql, insert, pg-dump, pg-restore

I’m trying to export data from my Postgres 9.5 instance on my Mac to my Postgres 9.5 db on an Ubuntu Linux box.  I’m using this command to export

```
pg_dump -U username --format plain --section data --inserts --file "t1.backup" --table “table1” --table “table2” --table "addresses" “mydb”
```

But when I import the data using pg_restore, I get errors

> pg_restore -d my_production --data-only t1.backup
>      …                                                         ^
>      Command was: INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (NULL, NULL, 1762000, '2016-12-10 05:07:41.857082', '2016-12-10 05:07:41.857207', 'Brendon Sch...
>   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "a6a40213-dcd8-4312-9ff1-ae6c23b31ade"
>   LINE 1: ..., '8a22784f-91aa-4b1e-a3d4-ec44f5de19ff', 55, 59, 'a6a40213-...

I think this is because although table2 has the same columns on both my Mac and Linux machines, they are in different orders.  How do I force INSERT statement to include the column names or barring that, how do I export/import my data successfully?  Note, I don’t want to delete the data on the remote machine, just add to it.

Comment: A plain text dump is a SQL script. You can't use `pg_restore` for that. You need to "run" the script using `psql`

Comment: Although @a_horse_with_no_name is already pointing the reason why pg_restore isn't working... in case you actually want 'column inserts', you can do it by means of `--column-inserts`

Comment: Yup the "--column-inserts" directive was exactly what I was looking for.